# proper structure of classes using interface classes

Tags: c#, object-oriented, .net, interface

Given the following two interfaces what would the proper way to set up the two actual classes?

```
public interface IPortfolio
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Id { get; set; }
    List<IDocument> Documents { get; set; }
}
public interface IDocument
{
    string ExtensionType { get; set; }
    int Id { get; set; }
    DateTime? DateFiled { get; set; }
    int? Size { get; set; }
    int? SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

The actual classes:

```
 public class Portfolio : IPortfolio
{
    public Portfolio()
    {
        Documents = new List<IDocument>();
    }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<IDocument> Documents { get; set; }
}

public class Document : IDocument
{
     public Document()
     {
       Pages = new List<IPage>();
     }
     public string ExtensionType { get; set; }
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public DateTime? DateFiled { get; set; }
     public int? Size { get; set; }
     public List<IPage> Pages { get; set; }
     public int? SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

When using the code above I get an error about not being able to implicitly convert *`List<Document> to List<IDocument>`*

This is a learning project to understand the concept of Interfaces and how they should best be used.

Comment: It sounds like you plan to create only one implementation per interface. If that's the case, then what's the reason for having those interfaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There no such thing like an interface class (term used in initial version of post). You have interfaces and classes implementing the interfaces.

I don't see any `List<Document>` in your code, but If you have defined the list as `List<IDocument>`, you must stick to this definition. You cannot assign it a `List<Document>`. But you can add `Document` objects to this list.

Generally two types `T<A>` and `T<B>` are not assignment compatible, even if `A` and `B` are assignment compatible. An exception is when the `in` or `out` keywords are used in generic interfaces. But this can only be done if the generic type occurs exclusively as input or exclusively as output as explained in [Variance in C#.NET 4.0 Covariance and Contravariance](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86419/Variance-in-C-NET-4-0-Covariance-and-Contravarianc).

I would convert the list properties `Documents` and `Pages` to getter-only properties.

```
public interface IPortfolio
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Id { get; set; }
    List<IDocument> Documents { get; }
}
```

And create the class like this

```
public class Portfolio : IPortfolio
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<IDocument> Documents { get; } = new List<IDocument>();
}
```

This makes the `Documents` property read-only. The list itself remains read/write.

```
var portfolio = new Portfolio();
portfolio.Documents.Add(new Document());
```